# Importing python modules using sublime text3

Tags: python-3.7

I'm learning Python 3.7, and Sublime Text3. Most programs run fine using control + b, but when I try to import a module from the standard library like random, I get the following error(Please note that I am not  running the program from OneDrive, but from my own computer!)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Documents\Python Programs\guess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Documents\Python Programs\random.py", line 1
    >>> import os
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Obviously the OneDrive thing is a problem ,but what can I do?
Many thanks.

Comment: Does the path environment variable contain the path to the Python folder as well as Scripts folder under Python root folder. e.g. C:\Program Files\Python37\ and C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\

Comment: Yes, path is correct, with both those added.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the error message that you want to focus on here is the last part of the stack trace, which is showing you the line that has the problem and where the problem is, i.e.:

```py
    >>> import os
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Based on this, your input file has the characters `>>>` in front of the import statement which, as the message indicates, is not valid Python syntax. Removing those characters should solve the problem for you. The line immediately above the error is showing you the name of the file that has the problem (in this case `random.py`).

The `>>>` is the prompt that the interactive Python interpreter gives you when you run it, as it's prompting you for what text to enter. That's not something that should appear in your code at all.

Comment: the >>> is not in the program, which is simply: import random
guess = random.randint(1,10)
print(guess)

Comment: Well then you need to investigate why the Python interpreter is seeing `>>> import os` as the first line of `C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Documents\Python Programs\random.py` when you don't see it when you look in the file, because that is clearly what it's angry about.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `random.py` file, as the error message states, it's a syntax error due to the the `>>>` repl symbol in there.

Comment: Hi, random is from the standard library. It works in the terminal and on IDLE

Comment: Well, the compiler sees a syntax error in those `>>>`, it's reading that line somewhere in that file.